# How to check a ReaLTaiizor text box content in C#

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a window form application and I am working with a third party library and I want to know how can I get the content of a text box.

I tried the normal text box by using MyTextboxName.Text, and It's prefectly working but the one I am using isn't...